# How does 'gpu.js' manipulate GPU threads?

Tags: javascript, gpu, gpu.js

I am working on an arbitrary-precision Mandelbrot fractal browser, and I want to take advantage of the GPU in order to do so. However; I don't really want to use anyone else's library for a few different reasons, and when i looked into gpu.js, nowhere does it say how it works. I've looked at the source code, but it's mangled beyond comprehension. If anybody could explain how it manipulates GPU threads, I would be elated!

Comment: The source code on github seems like it's not compressed or mangled.  https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js.  Also, be wary of NIH (Not Invented Here) bias.  _Especially_ in Javascript, it's _almost_ always better to use a library than to try to 'roll your own'.